# Capturing repeating groups in GO

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to create a function that can parse strings which consist of an uppercase word followed by zero or more arguments which are encapsulated in double quotes.

For example, each of the following lines:

```
COPY "filename one" "filename two"
REMOVE "filename"
LIST "x" "y" "z"
DISCONNECT
```

The result should be a string (the command) followed by a string[] (the arguments inside the quotes). I created the following regular expression:

```
re1, _ := regexp.Compile(`([A-Z]+)(?: "([^"]+)")*`)
results := re1.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1)
```

However, no-matter what I try, only the last argument gets captured.

An example of my problem: https://play.golang.org/p/W1rE1X4SWf5

`"arg1"` is not captured in this example. What am I missing?

Comment: Could a command (without considering args) contain white space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your commands are well defined, e.i. command names are always upper-case and arguments are always after the command then a looser regex might just fit your use case:

```
re1, _ := regexp.Compile(`([A-Z]+)|(?: "([^"]+)")`)
results := re1.FindAllStringSubmatch(`COMMAND "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"`, -1)

fmt.Println("Command:", results[0][1])
for _, arg := range results[1:] {
    fmt.Println("Arg:", arg[2])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/300L6U95paw)

Comment: Probably, ``regexp.Compile(`^([A-Z]+)| "([^"]+)"`)`` will be more precise as it matches the command at the start of string only.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to capture repeated match, only the last one is captured.
 I'd try to do it in two steps: first split commmand and arguments, then parse the arguments.

Splitting to command and arguments can be done with `([A-Z]+)((?: "[^"]+")*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDzBJu/1/)):

- `([A-Z]+)` in first group, you get the command
- `((?: "[^"]+")*)` in the second group, you'll get arguments in quotes, separated by spaces

Then you can use `FindAllString` with `"([^"]+)"` to extract arguments ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDzBJu/2/)).

Answer (score 1):

I think this may solve your problem

```
re1, _ := regexp.Compile(`([A-Z]+)(?: *)`)
commandText:=`COPY "filename one" "filename two"`
if re1.Match([]byte(commandText)){
    index:=re1.FindIndex([]byte(commandText))[1]
    commandArgs:=commandText[index:]
    commandArgsRegex,_:=regexp.Compile(`"([^"]+)"`)
    fmt.Println("Command= " , commandText[0:index])
    for i,arg:=range commandArgsRegex.FindAllString(commandArgs,-1){
        fmt.Println("args ", i,"= " , arg)
    }
}else{
    fmt.Println("Failed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra capture group.  If you make it optional extra data will be empty but the match will work

```
re1, _ := regexp.Compile(`^([A-Z]+)(\s"[^"]+")(\s"[^"]+")?(\s"[^"]+")?$`)
```

Add more `(\s"[^"]+")?` expressions up to the maximum you need.  I put in two as there is an expression with 3 parameters in your examples